# Windows Feature List blank, Updates fail, system readiness tool says files are corrupt

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-update, iis

I tried to install IIS and to my surprise the feature/components lists was blank =[. I tried the system update readiness tool and it creates the following log:

```
=================================
Checking System Update Readiness.
Binary Version 6.1.7100.4104
Package Version 5.0
2009-09-30 23:38

Checking Deployment Packages

Checking Package Manifests and catalogs.
(f) CBS MUM Corrupt 0x800F0900  servicing\packages\Package_1_for_KB973540~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.0.mum       Line 1: 
(f) CBS Catalog Corrupt 0x800B0100  servicing\packages\Package_1_for_KB973540~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.0.cat       
(f) CBS MUM Corrupt 0x800F0900  servicing\packages\Package_for_KB973540_RTM~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.0.mum     Line 1: 
(f) CBS Catalog Corrupt 0x800B0100  servicing\packages\Package_for_KB973540_RTM~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.0.cat     
(f) CBS MUM Corrupt 0x800F0900  servicing\packages\Package_for_KB973540~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.0.mum     Line 1: 
(f) CBS Catalog Corrupt 0x800B0100  servicing\packages\Package_for_KB973540~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.0.cat     

Checking package watchlist.

Checking component watchlist.

Checking packages.

Checking component store
(f) CSI Catalog Corrupt 0x800B0003  winsxs\Catalogs\efdfd17ac9909b9d81e1455d9abf291319237877c23df8a67a3f5a1f2f9e034f.cat    5fbf0b9691b..6772f1b0a58_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7100.4127_c2160c1f90006ee6    
(f) CSI Manifest All Zeros  0x00000000  WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_microsoft-windows-mediaplayer-wmpdxm_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7100.4127_none_35ba254677b2a294.manifest   amd64_microsoft-windows-mediaplayer-wmpdxm_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7100.4127_none_35ba254677b2a294 
(f) CSI Manifest All Zeros  0x00000000  WinSxS\Manifests\wow64_microsoft-windows-mediaplayer-wmpdxm_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7100.4127_none_400ecf98ac13648f.manifest   wow64_microsoft-windows-mediaplayer-wmpdxm_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7100.4127_none_400ecf98ac13648f 
Summary:
Seconds executed: 240
 Found 9 errors
  CSI Manifest All Zeros Total Count: 2
  CSI Catalog Corrupt Total Count: 1
  CBS MUM Corrupt Total Count: 3
  CBS Catalog Corrupt Total Count: 3
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when system update readiness tool fails your system is damaged beyond repair. You have two options at this point.

1. If you have your windows vista media available do an in place upgrade to repair the system. This will leave all your files and applications intact.
2. Re-install windows with the recovery partition that your OEM provided.

Answer (score 0):

- Start -> Run -> cmd.exe -> sfc
  /scannow

Note: **You must have ur installation CD**

If that doesnt fix it then:

- Start -> Run -> cmd.exe -> chkdsk /f

Answer (score 0):

**Windows Features list empty, not shown?**

When System Update Readiness Tool fails your system is not damaged beyond repair. You have an extra option to explore before trying System Restore or reïnstalling windows. See CheckSUR.log and remove dangling catalog entries from Component Based Servicing:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\Packages\

http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2009/03/06/fix-blank-or-empty-list-in-vista-turn-windows-features-on-or-off-optionalfeaturesexe/

Comment: Tags for search engines to match: WindowsUpdate_800B0100 WindowsUpdate_dt000 Windows update could not be installed because of error 2359302